# Dua'a for things you do not mean

Tags: allah, dua

Sometimes i subconsciously ask for bad things in my Dua'a that i don't want. Because i know that i'm not supposed to ask it, it just happens. e.g. i will make a Dua'a that my children will be happy and healthy and will outlive me. But then subconsciously i will think i hope they don't even though it's not what i want to happen. It just repeats in my head because i know i shouldn't think it. So does Allah accept Dua's we do not mean?

Answer (score 1):

Allah knows your intentions, and understands you very well, that what is in your heart. Dua is not like if you utter wrong words by your mouth then those wrong words will become true. So what you have in your heart, and your intentions, ONLY That will be accepted by Allah, and what you Actually mean to ask in dua, and not what you utter by mistake.

And Allah knows the best

Comment: Totally agreed with Farhan..

Comment: Salam, sorry to ask this, but yo you have references?

Answer (score 0):

Asalamualaikum when make Dua you need to move ur lips Allah S.W.T says ' i am with my slave as long has he remembers me and moving his lips'  Allah also Says 'i will not burden a soul for something that he can't control' Allah knows we don't want to make bad Dua and in in our head negetive toughts keep running that's why Allah has asked us to move our lips. Even if you make a dua from your heart and u move u lips , if you repent Allah S.W.T might cancel your dua(reject) and forgive you. You can always ask Allah to reject a Previous Dua by making dua for that to be rejected.