# Saying Wallahi when having bad thoughts about family members

Tags: allah, family, waswasa, evil-thoughts

Aoa

Sometimes I get bad thoughts in my head about my family members, for example "Wallahi (I swear to Allah) I hope that something bad happens to them." I do not mean anything like this and worry that this might make something horrible happen to them. My question is what should I do to stop these thoughts and whether I need to do something different as I keep saying Wallahi for horrible things in my thoughts.

Thanks so much

May Allah forgive us and guide us on the right path

Comment: does this answer your question : 
https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10036/duaa-for-things-you-do-not-mean?rq=1

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hadith

حَدَّثَنَا سَعِيدُ بْنُ مَنْصُورٍ، وَقُتَيْبَةُ بْنُ سَعِيدٍ، وَمُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عُبَيْدٍ الْغُبَرِيُّ، - وَاللَّفْظُ لِسَعِيدٍ - قَالُوا حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو عَوَانَةَ، عَنْ قَتَادَةَ، عَنْ زُرَارَةَ بْنِ أَوْفَى، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏

‏ إِنَّ اللَّهَ تَجَاوَزَ لأُمَّتِي مَا حَدَّثَتْ بِهِ أَنْفُسَهَا مَا لَمْ يَتَكَلَّمُوا أَوْ يَعْمَلُوا بِهِ ‏"

‏ ‏‏

It is narrated on the authority of Abu Huraira that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) observed:

Verily Allah forgave my people the evil promptings which arise within their hearts as long as they did not speak about them or did not act upon them.

Sahih Muslim 127 a
In-book : Book 1, Hadith 238
USC-MSA web (English) : Book 1, Hadith 230  (deprecated)
Sahih Muslim
As long as its in your thought you are excused
You should do dhikr(remberence of Allah) to save yourself from these thoguhts plus
You should greet your relatives and gave them gifts which increase love between you two plus removing these thoghts completly

Comment: Thank you for your help as it helps me understand my situation better.

Comment: One more question, so when I do dua for myself and for my family, I think thoughts like, "I don't want the dua to be accepted for one of my family members (ex.mom, dad, brother)." In reality, I do want the dua to be accepted for them and get quite anxious when these thoughts come. Please instruct me on this situation.

Comment: Abu Hurairah said; His companion came to him and said; Messenger of Allah! We have thoughts which we cannot dare talk about and we do not like that we have them or talk about them. He said:
Have you experienced that? They replied: yes. He said : that is clear faith.

Sahih (Al-Albani)

Sunan Abi Dawud 5111 
In-book : Book 43, Hadith 339 
English translation : Book 42, Hadith 5092
Abu Dawood

Comment: U are suffering waswas but remember just ignore it.acting on Waswas is not faith but resisting to is .Shaitan has many many means to distrct people.people which are not part of islam will never exprerience waswas coz shaitan has many ways to destroy them e.g by their haram desires.if you follow islam shaitan will comre to u by your desires and other things things but muslim show resistance against it  so he take form of waswas which make ibadat difficult for him and eventually after a long time he will find no joy in worship and may abandon the religion

Comment: Ignore and do dhikr.they are many dhikrs which havre many rewards and you can find in tthe aithentic hadiths books if you want i can gove u some dhikr books and also do the evening and morning  as it is very important.